# Closed form solution of sum of four squares given sum of five squares?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Lagrange's theorem states for all $n\in\mathbb N,\exists a',b',c',d'\in\mathbb N:a'^2+b'^2+c'^2+d'^2=n$.

Suppose we are given an $n$ and $a,b,c,d,e\in\mathbb N:a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2=n$ is there a way to find $a',b',c',d'\in\mathbb N:a'^2+b'^2+c'^2+d'^2=n$ in terms of $a,b,c,d,e$?

The point of the problem is to seek if there are extra structures to identifying sum of smaller number of squares from larger number.

Comment: “Closed-form solution” is too vague. But if it implies that $a',b',c',d'$ is computable in polynomial time from $a,b,c,d,e$, this would in fact imply that you can find an expression of any given $n$ as four squares in deterministic polynomial time, whereas only randomized polynomial-time algorithms are currently known.

Comment: $a'=f(a,b,c,d,e)$ where $f()$ is an arithmetic circuit. Probably weaker than what you are getting at.

Comment: You can evaluate an arithmetic circuit in polynomial time. (You can evaluate it modulo $n$ to avoid large intermediate results.) Hence what I wrote applies.

Comment: Why not just compute four squares from $n$?

Comment: Yeah that defeats the point of the problem to ask if there are extra structures.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek The coefficients of the circuit could be exponentially large integers.